# WebDriverSampler Tests are failing with Error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a simple test plan with a WebDriver Sampler test with Chrome Driver Config Element configured to use compatible Chromedriver in the <JMETER_HOME>/bin folder. It's a simple test, as in the two minutes guide. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/

It used to work well until recently and stopped working after upgrading the Chrome browser + driver.

JMeter Version 5.5
OS 12.6.4
Google Chrome : Version 111.0.5563.146 (Official Build) (arm64)
Plugin Manager and plugins were updated to the latest

I am getting the following error when the test is executed.

````
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:51531/devtools/browser/2fa15e06-54bb-4e59-a09f-1cb2b742d2d5
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.6.4', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:78) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:797) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:765) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:753) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
2023-04-07 11:37:16,235 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:51545/devtools/browser/e316304b-bf6b-46bf-96d7-28933b054a87
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.6.4', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:78) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.iterationStart(WebDriverConfig.java:198) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:99) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:266) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]```


  [1]: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ovXY.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmso4.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `--remote-allow-origins=*` line in the [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)

[image]

Also looking at `4.7.2` selenium version I don't think you have the latest  version of the WebDriver Sampler plugin as the latest WebDriver Sampler 4.8.3.1 comes with [Selenium 4.8.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.8.3) so consider upgrading or even reinstalling using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: It worked after reinstalling everything from the scratch.